# Access ServletContext in a ConstraintValidator

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, bean-validation

I wish to validate the input using a constraint validator. My problem is that I need some information contained in `ServletContext`, for example the path of properties file, to validate the request bean. I find that with Spring I can use `@Autowired` annotation, but unfortunately I can't use this framework.

The constraint:

```
@Constraint(validateBy = MyValidationClass.class)
@Target(PARAMETER)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface  MyValidation {
    ...
}
```

And what I wish do in constraint validator is something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(RequestBean value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    Properties props = servletContext.getAttribute("ws.props")
    // my validation
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>This might not be the best solution. (EDIT: You could find a better solution in my EDIT at the end)</s>

But I guess you could just create a `ServletContainerInitializer` that stores the `ServletContext` in a statical variable and access this inside the initializer.

What I don't find very nice here is that you than have a deep dependency to a static method. But otherwise you might find a way to hook into the process that instantiates the `ConstraintValidator`.

EDIT: I just looked up the Hibernator Validator documentation. And I guess this chapter here would be interesting for you, if you are using the Hibernator Validator implementation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#__code_constraintvalidatorfactory_code

According to this I would create an own `ConstraintValidatorFactory` and a new interface `ServletContextAware` with one setter `setServletContext(ServletContext)`.
Then the validator factory can check if the class that should be instantiated implements this interface and set the `ServletContext`.
The new `ConstraintValidatorFactory` could be used to create a new `ValidatorFactory` that will be used to create the required validators.

Just some not-checked code examples:

```java
interface ServletContextArea {
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext context);
}


public class ServletContextConstraintValidatorFactory implements ConstraintValidatorFactory {
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    public ServletContextConstraintValidatorFactory(ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
    }

    @Override
    public <T extends ConstraintValidator<?, ?>> T getInstance(Class<T> key) {
        // create instance from key as validator

        if(validator instanceof ServletContextAware) {
            ((ServletContextAware) validator).setServletContext(this.servletContext);
        }
        //...

        return validator;
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseInstance(ConstraintValidator<?, ?> instance) {
        //...
    }
}

// somewhere in the code where you have the servletContext available
ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byDefaultProvider()
    .configure()
    .constraintValidatorFactory( new ServletContextConstraintValidatorFactory(servletContext) )
    .buildValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();
```